# how i close dialog box through php script

Tags: php, iframe, dialog

```
    if(isset($_POST[submit])){  

       $exclude=array('submit');

       $sql ="insert into products set ";
       foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
          if(!in_array($k,$exclude)){
              $sql_array[]= mysql_real_escape_string($k)." = '".mysql_real_escape_string($v)."' ";
          }
       }

       $sql .= implode(",",$sql_array);
       $q=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
       if($q) {
          echo 'Inserted';
       }

    }
```

This coding is on iframe inside dialog box. I want to close dialog box after submitting form. How can i do this ?

Comment: also include dialog box code

Answer (score 1):

**step 1:**

add a js function in parent window which close the iframe

```
function close_iframe()
{
   $('#iframe_id').remove();
}
```

**step 2:**

call this js function from iframe when successfully inserted like

```
if($q){
     echo 'Inserted';
?>
         <script>
               parent.close_iframe();
         </script>
<?php
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this by using javascript as php cant work on client side. use this after submitting -

`echo "<script>
          window.close();
      </script>";`

this might work.

Comment: could anyone tell me the for for -1 so that i know the mistake